# If $G$ acts such that $\mbox{fix}(g) \in \{0,p\}$ for $g \ne 1$, $M$ maximal with $|G : M| = p$, then $|M / L| = p$ for semiregular $L \unlhd G$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, permutations, group-actions

Let $G$ be a solvable, nonregular and transitive permutation group acting on $\Omega$ such that each nontrivial element either fixes no point or exactly $p$ points for some prime $p$. And suppose that for $g \notin N_G(G_{\alpha})$ we have
$$
 G_{\alpha} \cap G_{\alpha}^g = 1.
$$
Suppose that $p$ is the smallest prime dividing $|G|$. Let $M$ be a maximal normal subgroup of $G$. Suppose $|G / M| = p$ and that $M$ is intransitive, then $M$ has $p$ orbits and by maximality $M_{\alpha} = G_{\alpha}$. Let $\Delta$ be the orbit of $M$ containing $\alpha$, and suppose that $\Delta$ contains all $p$ fixed points of $G_{\alpha}$. Further assume $L$ is a normal subgroup of $M$ which is regular on $\Delta$ and that $|M_{\alpha}| = p$ and $O_{p'}(G) = 1$.

> Why then $|M / L| = p$ and it follows that $G$ has a normal subgroup $S$ such that $|G / S| = p^2$ and $S \le M$?

I see that the set of fixed points of $G_{\alpha}$ is a minimal block, and by the assumption that $\Delta$ contains all of them we must have $|\Delta| = k\cdot p$. Also as $L$ acts regular on $\Delta$, we have $|L| = |\Delta|$, and $M_{\alpha}$ operates equivalent on $L$ by conjugation as on $\Delta$. Also if $|M / L| = p$, then $|G : L| = |G : M||M : L| = p^2$, but $L$ need not be normal in $G$, so the subgroup $S$ need to be constructed in some other way?

Comment: I don't see immediately why $|M/L|=p$. Can you tell me where this comes from?

Comment: Thanks for taking a look! It is from the paper *On permutation groups in which non-trivial elements have $p$ fixed points or none* by Pretzel & Schleiermacher, page 480, 4th paragraph. Do you have access to this paper? Maybe it is relevant that $p$ is odd; further they have shown that $|M_{\alpha}| = p$ and $O_{p'}(G) = 1$, I will put this as an assumption into the text but otherwise I guess I have put all assumptions in the question as far as I can see.

Comment: But $|M/L|=|M_\alpha|$, so that makes it clear! The image of the action of $G$ on the right cosets of $L$ must be a $p$-groups (since $p$ is the smallest prime dividing $|G|$) in which the image of $M$ has index $p$, so by properties of $p$-groups there is a normal subgroup of $G$ of index $p^2$ contaied in $M$.

Comment: Ok, the first one is indeed clear as $|L| = |M:M_{\alpha}|$. But that the image of the action is a $p$-group I do not see. If $\Omega$ is the set of cosets of $L$ in $G$, then $|\Omega| = p^2$. Denote by $\pi : G \to \mbox{Sym}(\Omega)$ this action. Set $L_G = \bigcap_{g\in G} L^g$. Then $|\pi(G)| = |G : L_G| = |G : L||L : L_G| = p^2 \cdot |L : L_G|$ and we have that $|\pi(G)|$ must divide $|G|$ and $p^2! = |\mbox{Sym}(\Omega)|$. But I do not see that this is strong enough to enforce that $\pi(G)$ is a $p$-group?

Comment: The action is imprimitive with $p$ blocks of size $p$ (the orbits of $M$), so the order of the image divides $(p!)^{p+1}$.

Comment: Ah okay nice observation because then it could be decomposed into an action on the $p$ orbits (a subgroup of $S_p$) and actions on the individual orbits of size $p$ (hence could also be seen as subgroups of $S_p$) giving your formulae. Yes and with that I see that $|L : L_G| = p^k$ for some $k$, as the other divisors $< p$ are not possible.