# If $G$ is solvable and acts such that $\mbox{fix}(g) \in \{0,p\}$ for $g \ne 1$ and $M$ maximal, why is $N_M(M_{\alpha}) \in \mbox{Syl}_p(M)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, permutations, group-actions

Let $p$ be an odd prime. Suppose $G$ is solvable and acts as a nonregular and transitive permutation group on $\Omega$ such that each nontrivial element either fixes no point or exactly $p$ points. Also suppose that for $g \notin N_G(G_{\alpha})$ we have
$$
 G_{\alpha} \cap G_{\alpha}^g = 1.
$$
Suppose that $p$ is the smallest prime dividing the order of $G$.

Assume we have a maximal normal intransitive subgroup $M$ of index $p$. Let $\Delta$ be the orbit of $M$ containing $\alpha$, and suppose all $p$ fixed point of $G_{\alpha}$ are contained in $\Delta$ and that $M_{\alpha}$ is a $p$-group with $|M_{\alpha}| > p$.

> Why is $N_M(M_{\alpha}) = P$ a Sylow $p$-subgroup of $M$?

As $|N_M(M_{\alpha}) : M_{\alpha}|$ equals the number of fixed point of $M_{\alpha}$ on $\Delta$, and we have exactly $p$ such fixed point, we have $|N_M(M_{\alpha}) : M_{\alpha}| = p$, and as $M_{\alpha}$ is a $p$-group, its normalizer in $M$ is also a $p$-group, but why is it a Sylow $p$-subgroup. If not then it would be contained in a Sylow $p$-subgroup $Q$, and $P < N_Q(P) \le Q$. But I do not see where this would be a contradiction?

Comment: Because $|\Delta| \equiv p \bmod |M_\alpha|$.

Comment: Yes, thank you! So that $|M : M_{\alpha}| = |\Delta| = mp^k + p = p(mp^{k-1} + 1)$ with $k > 1$, and so $mp^{k-1} + 1$ is not divisible by $p$. Maybe if you have the time I would find it really kind if you take a look at my other related question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1573631/if-g-acts-such-that-mboxfixg-in-0-p-for-g-ne-1-m-maximal-wit There I am unsure why regular normal subgroups have index $p$ in $M$.